# Creating guava Table from Map

Tags: java, guava

I have a Map data structure as mentioned below. I want to convert this into Table. I am trying to achieve this using `Tables.newCustomTable()` method but getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
    at com.google.common.collect.Tables.newCustomTable(Tables.java:299)
```

**The Code is:**

```
public class TestClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> data = Maps.newHashMap();
    Map<Integer, String> internalMap = Maps.newHashMap();

    internalMap.put(1, "A");
    internalMap.put(2, "B");
    internalMap.put(3, "C");

    data.put(1, internalMap);
    data.put(2, internalMap);
    data.put(3, internalMap);

    Table<Integer, Integer, String> table = table(data);
    System.out.println(table);
  }

  public static <R, C, V> Table<R, C, V> table(Map<R, Map<C, V>> toTable) {
    return Tables.newCustomTable(toTable, new Supplier<Map<C, V>>() {
      @Override
      public Map<C, V> get() {
        return Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#newCustomTable%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier%29) of `Tables.newCustomTable` clearly says:

```
Throws:
IllegalArgumentException - if backingMap is not empty
```

So you must provide an empty map, but you filled it with some data.

EDIT as per the comments:

The method `Tables.newCustomTable` does not transform an already data containing map into a *table view*. It is used for a more custom behavior when it comes to create the underyling maps. In fact, the method `Tables.newCustomTable` only gives more control over the concrete type of maps that should be created for rows and columns. For example, it can be used as following:

```
public static <R extends Comparable<R>, C, V> Table<R, C, V> createTable() {
    return Tables.newCustomTable(Maps.newTreeMap(), new Supplier<Map<C, V>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<C, V> get() {
            return Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I used `TreeMap` for the rows and `LinkedHashMap` for the columns. (I needed to constrain the type parameter R to extend `Comparable`, by the way.)

In most cases you do not need that behavior and thus you can write your method as following:

```
public static <R, C, V> Table<R, C, V> table(Map<R, Map<C, V>> fromTable)
{
    Table<R, C, V> table = HashBasedTable.create();
    for (R rowKey : fromTable.keySet())
    {
        Map<C, V> rowMap = fromTable.get(rowKey);
        for (C columnKey : rowMap.keySet())
        {
            V value = rowMap.get(columnKey);
            table.put(rowKey, columnKey, value);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean internalMap should be empty?

Comment: I think, you wanted the map referenced by the variable `data` (and thus referenced by the `toTable` parameter) to be the _data supplying_ map. That means you have to rewrite your supplier. And vice versa: The empty map you created with `Maps.newLinkedHashMap()` should be placed as the first argument.

Comment: Can you help with code snippet? It would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Tables.newCustomTable() does not allow create table from already created Map (populated with data). Correct?

Comment: @user3222372 I am not really familiar with Guava's tables. Let me have a look. Maybe I can help you later ...

Comment: Thanks. I will have to loop through to convert from Map to Table.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <R, C, V> Table<R, C, V> table(Map<R, Map<C, V>> fromTable)
{
    Table<R, C, V> table = HashBasedTable.create();
    for (R rowKey : fromTable.keySet())
    {
        Map<C, V> rowMap = fromTable.get(rowKey);
        for (C columnKey : rowMap.keySet())
        {
            V value = rowMap.get(columnKey);
            table.put(rowKey, columnKey, value);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```